# Unknown encoding: buffer when pushing to stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I'm implementing a simple transform stream that reads a string from a stream, operates on it, and then spits it out.  My implementation of `_transform` (the important part) looks like:

```
_transform = function (chunk, enc, done) {                      
    var x,                                                                      
        str = chunk.toString();                                                 

    for (x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {                                          
        this.push(doTransformation(str.charCodeAt(x)), enc);
    }                                                                           
    done();                                                                     
};
```

Right now, `doTransformation` will just return return the character from that char code, so this is effectively just `this.push(str[x])`.  When testing this using:

```
process.stdin
    .pipe(explosionPillsTransform())
    .pipe(process.stdout)
```

I get the error

> TypeError: Unknown encoding: buffer

This seems to be because `enc` is buffer.  Actually everything works perfectly if I remove the `enc` argument from `this.push`, as in:

```
this.push(doTransformation(str.charCodeAt(x)))
```

... but some examples that I've seen have used this second argument.  Is there a good way for me to know when to use the encoding argument or when to omit it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'buffer' encoding is redundant if `chunk` is already a Buffer. If you are calling `push()` with a string, then you need to specify the correct encoding. If you're passing in a Buffer instead, then you can drop the `enc` if it's set to 'buffer'.

Comment: I am calling `push` with a string since I'm using `toString` on the `chunk`, right?

Comment: If `doTransformation()` returns a string, then you need to pass the proper string encoding that results from calling that function (e.g. 'ascii' or 'utf8').

Comment: How do I know what the encoding of the returned string is?

Comment: That's entirely dependent on the behavior of your `doTransformation()` function.

Comment: All it does is `return String.fromCharCode(arguments[0])`

Comment: Then you should be safe with 'utf8'.

Answer (score 3):

From the node.js documentation, the second argument to [Stream#push()](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) should be

> encoding String Encoding of String chunks. Must be a valid Buffer encoding, such as 'utf8' or 'ascii'

I would recommend always passing the encoding - if you actually know what it is. Otherwise, someone, somewhere is going to have to guess whether that byte sequence "0xC3 0xA8" should have been "Ã¨" or è.

Comment: But when the encoding is `buffer` I can't pass it without getting this error

Comment: Because `buffer` isn't an encoding. Valid encodings are things like 'utf8' or 'ascii'.

Comment: So in my code should I just check whether `enc` is `buffer`?

Comment: I don't know where your `enc` is coming from when _transform is being called, but if it's a buffer, it's not an encoding. Look up the stack at the caller to see if the actual encoding information is available; if it is, make sure that is what comes into _transform as the 2nd argument, instead of the buffer.

Comment: Just to complete the circle here: despite what the Node.js documentation says, `'buffer'` (the string) is a valid value for `enc` as of Node 20, but only if `Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) === true`. If `Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) !== true` but `enc === 'buffer'` then you'll get the error seen in the OP. Additionally, AFAIK streams not operating in object mode will (always?) invoke `_transform`/`_write` with `'buffer'` as the second argument.